# Pipe Delimited CSV File to HTML (But Values have Commas)

Tags: php, csv

I am in the process of turning this CSV File of quotes to a HTML Table. The CSV Table is formatted as such:

The old world is dying, and a new world struggles to be born; now is the time of monsters.|Antonio Gramsci|1891-1937

The unexamined life is not worth living.|Socrates|c.469-399 B.C.

When converting it to an array by

```
<?php
        $file = fopen("quotes.csv", "r");

        $data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "|");

        $arr = [];
        
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "|")) !== false) {
            $arr[] = $data;
        }

        echo "<pre>";print_r($arr)
  
?>
```

1st Row gives me

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => The old world is dying, and a new world struggles to be born; now is the time of monsters.|Antonio Gramsci|1891-1937|
```

Whereas 2nd row Correctly Gives me this output

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => The unexamined life is not worth living.
            [1] => Socrates
            [2] => c.469-399 B.C.
        )
```

How can I make the first row give me the output of the 2nd row? I know it has something to do with that comma in the first column but how do I work around that?

Comment: This is not my experience when [I try to emulate your findings](https://3v4l.org/uI0Cj). Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What I do notice is that you use `fgetcsv()` twice, and the data of one is ignored. Is that intentional? You also don't close the `<pre>` tag. Could it be that you assembled the code in your question in a slightly sloppy fashion?